# Not able to visit a url in cypress test, but working fine otherwise

Tags: javascript, browser, cypress, load-balancing

I am trying to visit a URL through cypress test but is giving me the below error. If I copy and past the same URL in a different browser it works fine.

Also, if I copy-paste the URL into a new tab in the same browser in which cypress is running the automated test it again shows 464. So I am concluding the is an issue with the automated browser.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the following relates to your problem.

[Load balancer troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html)

> **HTTP 464**
> The load balancer received an incoming request protocol that is incompatible with the version config of the target group protocol.
>
> Possible causes:
>
> - The request protocol is an HTTP/1.1, while the target group protocol version is a gRPC or HTTP/2.
> - The request protocol is a gRPC, while the target group protocol version is an HTTP/1.1.
> - The request protocol is an HTTP/2 and the request is not POST, while target group protocol version is a gRPC.

You should fix the issue rather than try to avoid it with flags to ignore it.

Comment: Yes, it seems so, I checked with the devs they have configured something load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `failOnStatusCode` as false so that cypress doesn't fail on getting a response code of 464.

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com', {failOnStatusCode: false})
```

You can also try with `retryOnStatusCodeFailure`. Definition - Whether Cypress should automatically retry status code errors under the hood. Cypress will retry a request up to 4 times if this is set to true.

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com', {retryOnStatusCodeFailure: true})
```

Or with `retryOnNetworkFailure`. Definition - Whether Cypress should automatically retry transient network errors under the hood. Cypress will retry a request up to 4 times if this is set to true.

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com', {retryOnNetworkFailure: true})
```

In case you want to pass two options together you can do like this:

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com', {
  failOnStatusCode: false,
  retryOnStatusCodeFailure: true,
})
```

Comment: Did that it's not only a response error I am unable to visit the page and if copy pastes the URL in the browser in a new tab it's again saying cannot visit. Then u do the same with a normal browser the page opens.

Comment: Alapan, it seems this is a load balancer issue but thanks a ton the above methods will come in handy.